# How can I allow use es2018 regex in JavaScript/TypeScript in IDEA

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

How can I allow to use es2018 regex in JavaScript/TypeScript in IntelliJ IDEA or disable this error notice only?

`(?<=)` is es2018 look-behind

I have tried adding `///<reference lib="es2018.regexp"/>` but this error notice still exists.

- IntelliJ IDEA/WebStorm is an IDE (can be used for JavaScript/TypeScript development)
- My env is Node.js 10 (support es2018.regexp)
- My script is run in Node.js, not browser

Comment: does your browser support es2018 and what error are you getting?

Comment: Which browser are you using and which version?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy im use nodejs 10 it allow use this, but idea show error notice

Comment: Please re-read my question, nodejs is not a browser.

Comment: @ChrisLi my env is support it, just idea will show error msg in ide

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy my script is run in nodejs, i didn't need use it at browser

Comment: can't recreate for javaScript; reproduced in .ts files, please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34805 for updates

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your project has a tsconfig.json file with compiler's option. Use the lib option and specify ES2018 there. This library contains type definition for ES2018 API. For example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2018"
    ]
  }
}
```

For details on compiler's options see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: this not work, i think problem is happen on idea, because typescript didn't show any notice about this